# How to use PostSharp to lo log text using TestContext.WriteLine

Tags: mstest, postsharp

I have a TestBase class from which each test derives, the class is as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestBase
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    protected HelperSelenium SeleniumHelper { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitBase()
    {
        SeleniumHelper = new HelperSelenium(TestContext);    
    }
}
```

As you can see, TestBase instantiates TestContext, which is needed to log text to the test (`console` and `debug` are not viable as it would print in each test that is being executed at the moment if it is running in parallel). Then I need the `TestContext` in the `[TestMethod]` to be able to log the message:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestMethod1 : TestBase
{
    ...

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine("Starting TestInitialize...");
        ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine("Starting TestMethod...");
        ...
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine("Starting TestCleanup...");
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

My question is if it is possible to intercept TestContext with PostSharp and then intercept the calls to `[TestInitialize]`, `[TestMethod]` and `[TestCleanup]` so I can add the writeline outside the test.

I am just starting with PostSharp and don't have much knowledge, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of logging the start and end of your testing methods you can implement a custom [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator). I understand that you also want to use the `TestContext` property of the test class to do your logging. PostSharp allows you to [import and access a member](https://doc.postsharp.net/members) of the target class if you implement `IInstanceScopedAspect`.

You can use the following example as a starting point:

```
[PSerializable]
public class TestTracingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    private string testMethodName;

    [ImportMember("TestContext")]
    public Property<TestContext> TestContextImported;

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        this.testMethodName = method.Name;
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }

    public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        this.TestContextImported.Get().WriteLine($"Starting {this.testMethodName}");
    }
}
```

You can then apply your custom tracing attribute to your test classes and methods.

```
[TestClass]
[TestTracing]
public class TestClass1
{
}
```